# How to resolve "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 307200 bytes) in ........" error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a Stored Procedure on my production server as below:

```
delimiter ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAssessmentData`(
    IN inRefNo VARCHAR(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        AssessmentID, 
        P.PartName, P.PartNo, P.PartTypeID, T.VehiclePartType AS PartType,
        AmountClaimed, Price, IsRateOnMRP, GSTRate, GSTAmount, DepreciationRate, DepreciationAmount, AmountAssessed
        FROM assessment V
        LEFT JOIN cdn.vehicle_parts P ON P.PartID = V.PartID
        LEFT JOIN cdn.vehicle_part_types T ON T.VehiclePartTypeID = P.PartTypeID
        WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
END
;;
delimiter ;
```

Script for table **assessments**:

```
CREATE TABLE `assessment`  (
  `RefNo` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Reference number to an interim survey',
  `AssessmentID` tinyint(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Numeric ID assigned to an assessment',
  `PartID` smallint(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reference to cdn.vehicle_parts',
  `AmountClaimed` int(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Amount of claim requested by vehicle owner',
  `Price` int(7) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Price of part being assessed, inclusive of GST or execlusive of GST',
  `IsRateOnMRP` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Wether rate of part is on MRP - YES | NO',
  `GSTRate` tinyint(2) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Percentage of GST on part',
  `GSTAmount` smallint(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Amount of GST',
  `DepreciationRate` tinyint(2) NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Percentage of depreciation on part',
  `DepreciationAmount` smallint(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Amount of depreciation on part',
  `AmountAssessed` int(7) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Amount assessed by surveyor (MRP - Depreciation)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`RefNo`, `AssessmentID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Script for table **vehicle_parts**:

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle_parts`  (
  `PartID` smallint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Numeric ID asigned to the part',
  `PartName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the part as per company brochure',
  `PartNo` varchar(14) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Part number provided by vehicle manufacturer',
  `PartTypeID` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reference to table: vehicle_part_types',
  `VehicleTypeID` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Referene to table: vehicle_types',
  `VehicleMakeID` smallint(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reference to table: vehicle_makes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PartID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 45 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Script for table **vehicle_part_types**:

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle_part_types`  (
  `VehiclePartTypeID` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Single character code for part type',
  `VehiclePartType` char(7) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Type of part',
  PRIMARY KEY (`VehiclePartTypeID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

The script to execute the query in PHP is:

```
$dbh->query("CALL GetAssessmentData('$refNo');");
```

**$dbh** is the object of class which I have created for database access using PDO. Script for function **query** is:

```
private function query($query, $params){
  $result = null;
  $stmt = null;
  $single_row = null;
  $this->open();
  try{
     $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
     if(!is_null($params)){ # If a parameterized query is to be executed
        $this->bindValueArray($stmt, $params);
     }
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex){
     $errorDB = $stmt->errorInfo();
     $trace = $ex->getTraceAsString();
     $this->error = '<b>PDOException: </b><br /><pre>'.print_r($errorDB, TRUE).'<hr />'.$trace.'</pre><hr />';
     $this->WriteErrorLog($query, htmlentities($this->error));
  }
  catch(Exception $ex){
     $trace = $ex->getTraceAsString();
     $this->error = 'Exception: <pre>'.$ex->getTraceAsString().'</pre>';
     $this->WriteErrorLog($query, htmlentities($this->error));
  }
  $stmt = NULL;
  return $result;
}
```

I've been using this function since years. So seems like there may not be a problem with it.

The query `CALL GetAssessmentData('$refNo');` works perfectly on localhost and remote server using Navicat, MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin.

But when I execute the query in my PHP script, it throws the error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 307200 bytes) in ........

The hosting company has provided my 256MB RAM. The **assessment** table has only 4 records. Also, I can execute all other over 40 procedures nicely with same script.

Comment: What result size may there be? The [fetchAll() could be problematic](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall) depending upon the sheer number of records.

Comment: As I said, there are only 4 rows in the table.

Comment: Doh!, apologies, ... I overlooked that. But how to know is it THAT specific query? The query function looks like it can be used for any query.

Comment: You're right. I can be.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked which line triggers that error?